# How can I ensure that illegal behavior is unexecutable?

Tags: f#, functional-programming, state-machine

**How do I make illegal behavior unexecutable?**

Summary:

Since starting my journey to learn F#, I am learning about Type-Driven Design and Property-based Testing. As a result, I fell in love with the idea of making illegal states unrepresentable.

But what I would really like to do is to make illegal behavior unexecutable.

I am learning F# by writing a BlackJack game. As a result, I want to ensure that when a dealer distributes cards, that the dealer can only deal an "initial hand" or a "hit". All other distributions of cards are illegal.

In C#, I would implement the Strategy Pattern and thus, create a DealHandCommand and a DealHitCommand. Then I would hard-code a constant integer value for the number of cards to deal-out (per strategy).

DealHandCommand = 2 cards

DealHitCommand = 1 card

Based on these strategies, I would then implement a state-machine to represent a session of a BlackJack game. Hence, after I deal the initial hand (i.e. DealHandCommand), I perform a state transition in which future deals can only execute the "DealHitCommand".

**Specifically, does it make sense to implement a state-machine within a hybrid-functional language in order to achieve illegal behavior as unexecutable?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's easy to implement a state machine in F#. It usually follows a three-step process, with the third step being optional:

1. Define a Discriminated Union with a case for each state
2. Define a transition function for each case
3. Optional: implement all the rest of the code

## Step 1

In this case it sounds to me like there are two states:

- An initial *Hand* with two cards
- A *Hit* with an extra card

That suggests this `Deal` discriminated union:

```
type Deal = Hand of Card * Card | Hit of Card
```

Also, define what a `Game` is:

```
type Game = Game of Deal list
```

Notice the use of a single-case discriminated union; [there's a reason for that](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-single-case-dus).

## Step 2

Now define a function that transitions from each state to a `Game`.

It turns out that you can't transition *from* any game state to the `Hand` case, because a `Hand` is what *starts* a new game. On the other hand (pun intended) you need to supply the *cards* that go into the hand:

```
let init c1 c2 = Game [Hand (c1, c2)]
```

The other case is when a game is in progress, you should only allow `Hit`, but not `Hand`, so define this transition:

```
let hit (Game deals) card = Game (Hit card :: deals)
```

As you can see, the `hit` function requires you to pass in an existing `Game`.

## Step 3

What prevents a client from creating an invalid `Game` value, e.g. `[Hand; Hit; Hand; Hit; Hit]`?

You can encapsulate the above state machine with a [signature file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233196.aspx):

**BlackJack.fsi:**

```
type Deal
type Game
val init : Card -> Card -> Game
val hit : Game -> Card -> Game
val card : Deal -> Card list
val cards : Game -> Card list
```

Here, the types `Deal` and `Game` are declared, but their 'constructors' aren't. This means that you can't directly create values of these types. This, for example, doesn't compile:

```
let g = BlackJack.Game []
```

The error given is:

> error FS0039: The value, constructor, namespace or type 'Game' is not defined

The only way to create a `Game` value is to call a function that creates it for you:

```
let g =
    BlackJack.init
        { Face = Ace; Suit = Spades }
        { Face = King; Suit = Diamonds }
```

This also enables you to continue the game:

```
let g' = BlackJack.hit g { Face = Two; Suit = Spades }
```

You may have noticed that the above signature file also defines two functions to get the cards out of `Game` and `Deal` values. Here are the implementations:

```
let card = function
    | Hand (c1, c2) -> [c1; c2]
    | Hit c -> [c]

let cards (Game deals) = List.collect card deals
```

A client can use them like this:

```
> let cs = g' |> BlackJack.cards;;
>

val cs : Card list = [{Suit = Spades;
                       Face = Two;};
                      {Suit = Spades;
                       Face = Ace;};
                      {Suit = Diamonds;
                       Face = King;}]
```

Notice that this approach is mostly structural; there are few moving parts.

## Appendix

These are the files used above:

**Cards.fs:**

```
namespace Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q34042428.Cards

type Suit = Diamonds | Hearts | Clubs | Spades
type Face =
    | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten
    | Jack | Queen | King | Ace

type Card = { Suit: Suit; Face: Face }
```

**BlackJack.fsi:**

```
module Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q34042428.Cards.BlackJack

type Deal
type Game
val init : Card -> Card -> Game
val hit : Game -> Card -> Game
val card : Deal -> Card list
val cards : Game -> Card list
```

**BlackJack.fs:**

```
module Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q34042428.Cards.BlackJack

open Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q34042428.Cards

type Deal = Hand of Card * Card | Hit of Card

type Game = Game of Deal list

let init c1 c2 = Game [Hand (c1, c2)]

let hit (Game deals) card = Game (Hit card :: deals)

let card = function
    | Hand (c1, c2) -> [c1; c2]
    | Hit c -> [c]

let cards (Game deals) = List.collect card deals
```

**Client.fs:**

```
module Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q34042428.Cards.Client

open Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q34042428.Cards

let g =
    BlackJack.init
        { Face = Ace; Suit = Spades }
        { Face = King; Suit = Diamonds }
let g' = BlackJack.hit g { Face = Two; Suit = Spades }

let cs = g' |> BlackJack.cards
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. In the fsi file, if we did want to explicitly enable the outside world to use "Game", how would we express that? Would it just be "type Game()" within the fsi file?

Comment: @ScottNimrod If you wanted to do that, the easiest way would be to delete the `.fsi` file, because then the normal module declaration would be in effect. Otherwise, I'm sure [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233196.aspx) can tell you how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

a *hit* is one more card right?

If so then just use two **types**:

- `type HandDealt = Dealt of Card * Card`
- and `type Playing = Playing of Cards`
- (maybe more - depends on what you want).

Then instead of *Commands* you have simple functions:

- `dealHand :: Card * Card -> HandDealt`
- `start :: HandDealt -> Playing`
- `dealAnother :: Playing -> Card -> Playing`

this way you can only follow a certain behavior and it's statically checked.

of couse you probably want to extend those types to multiple players but I think you get what I am going to

---

PS: maybe you even like to skip the `HandDealt` / `start` phase (if you don't need the middle phase for things like betting/splitting/etc. - but please mind that I have no clue about blackjack):

- `dealHand :: Card * Card -> Playing`
- `dealAnother :: Playing -> Card -> Playing`

it's up to you

Answer (score 1):

One of the possibilities could be using discriminated union:

```
type DealCommand =
    | Hand of Card * Card
    | Hit of Card
```

(assuming you have type `Card`)